# Is there way to and how deploy jquery on top of redux?

Tags: jquery, node.js, reactjs, redux, deployment

i'm about asking for help with a Redux/React js, as the 10 freelance modern JS technicians gave up on this task.
The script in question is from the WordPress commercial theme i've purchased and the author denied to provide support as the support license expired (unused).

So, the theme's front-site page is generated via Redux WP plugin by file named "theme.js". It is containing javascript compressed code that is too complex to manually edit while my task is just to move a few div content blocks from the default positions into new and have somewhat more appealing page layout.

Would interested here, take a look at the scripts in the attachment, "theme.js" is the actual generated layout file, the "edit-blocks-positioning.txt" are the listed block modifications i want to apply (into theme.js*) and it's jquery version is the "jquery-mod.js"(**),

- please suggest how to edit(*) or how to have jQuery(**) to work on top of the Redux generated "theme.js".

I've read about React, Node JS etc.Modern Framework JS, where are provided standard ways to have working jQuery as with import jquey, custom library method "nodeQuery", ES6 syntax for jquery import and also "expose-loader" of "webpack" as this script is working under 10's of js frameworks libraries as React, Node, Babel, WebPack... still with all NPM modules installed around 100k files, set and tested but no avail on this small task!

To add, i've the simplest applicable solution "jquery-mod.js" working albeit only with the opened browser Development Tools.

Files

https://file.io/nUqv7M01rNeP

edit-blocks-positioning.txt 3 KB
theme.js 2 MB

jquery-mod.js :

```
 jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('section.product--section:nth-child(1)').insertBefore('.profile--owner');
        jQuery('.product--actions.flex.justify-between.py-14.pl-24.pr-30.bg-grey-100').insertBefore('.product--advertisement.mt-30');
        jQuery('.product--section.product--section__actions.flex.flex-wrap.justify-between.mb-20').insertBefore('.product--advertisement.mt-30');
    });
```

This is what i need to edit within theme.js   `
//product id block:

```
l.default.createElement("section",{className:"product--section product--section__meta flex flex-wrap mb-20 justify-between items-center item-info"},l.default.createElement("div",{className:"flex"},l.default.createElement("div",{className:"product--id text-grey-1000 text-13 font-light"},(0,c.sprintf)(lc_data.jst[504],o.ID)),(null==e||null===(t=e.options)||void 0===t?void 0:t.published_date)&&""!==(null==e||null===(n=e.options)||void 0===n?void 0:n.published_date)&&l.default.createElement("div",{className:"product--date text-grey-1000 mt-10 ml-10 text-13 font-light "},(0,c.sprintf)(lc_data.jst[728],null==e||null===(r=e.options)||void 0===r?void 0:r.published_date))),!e.premiumOnly&&!o.is_expired&&l.default.createElement("div",{className:"product--info"},l.default.createElement(g.default,{product:o,currentUser:x,options:e.options})),(null==o?void 0:o.is_expired)&&l.default.createElement("div",{className:"py-6 px-10 rounded border border-red-300 bg-red-100 text-base text-red-500"},lc_data.jst[711]))
```

//product id block, before:

```
,e.createElement("div",{className:"w-full sm:w-2/3"},e.createElement("div",{className:"profile--owner"},
```

////product id block

//add to compare block:

```
l.default.createElement("div",{className:"product--actions flex justify-between py-14 pl-24 pr-30 bg-grey-100"},"widget"!==e.options.calculator_position&&o.product_meta.price>0&&o.calculator&&o.calculator.display&&l.default.createElement(_.default,{product:o,currentUser:x}),"0"!==e.options.ad_compare&&l.default.createElement(b.default,{product:o,currentUser:x,options:S}))
```

//add to compare block, before:

```
e.createElement("div",{className:"product--advertisement mt-30"} ...
```

////add to compare block

//likes views share print widget:

```
!(0,a.default)(o)&&!o.is_expired&&l.default.createElement("section",{className:"product--section product--section__actions flex flex-wrap justify-between mb-20"},l.default.createElement("div",{className:"product--actions__left flex flex-wrap"},!(0,a.default)(x)&&l.default.createElement(d.default,{product:o,currentUser:x}),l.default.createElement(f.default,{product:o}),"0"!==e.options.ad_visits&&(null==o?void 0:o.views)&&("always"===S["membership-listings-visits"]||"logged_in"===S["membership-listings-visits"]&&"1"===lc_data.logged_in)&&l.default.createElement(p.default,{product:o}),!(0,a.default)(lc_data.user_ip)&&"0"!==e.options.ad_likes&&l.default.createElement(m.default,{product:o,currentUser:x}),!(0,a.default)(lc_data.user_ip)&&"no"!==e.options.report&&l.default.createElement(h.default,{product:o,options:e.options}),"small-screen"===T&&l.default.createElement(v.default,{product:o})),"default"===T&&l.default.createElement("div",{className:"product--actions__right"},l.default.createElement(v.default,{product:o})))
```

//likes views share print widget, before:

```
e.createElement("div",{className:"product--advertisement mt-30"} ...
```

////likes views share print widget

`

Comment: Could you please add the code you mention as in an attachment to the body of your question?

Comment: I've also read about caching causing the described situation when the scripts are working with a Dev Tools opened, but aside this application' server side Virtual DOM, other WP applications are working with their per directory Cache-Control HTTP header so, no server side general settings issues, except maybe if Redux is somehow utilizing LiteSpeed Cache as of non existing settings?

Comment: Hello, here are some of the code producing components, as i don't think am allowed to share entire install during commercial licensing.

Comment: Redux plugin: 'https://file.io/igbY53bwUNMM'

Packge json 'https://file.io/H07mqi5qnJSh'

Comment: Here are listed all licensed JS Frameworks in use: 'https://file.io/d20AHRPj7qj7' and there are more JS Framework files out of scope of this licensed list as babel, backbone and others.

Comment: //per react documentation jQuery is enabled via componentDidMount, but that works only in class element componentDidMount() { const script = document.createElement("script"); script.src = "example.com/script.js"; script.async = true; document.body.appendChild(script); } }); Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: '{' –

Comment: //so the equivalent to componentDidMount outside of class element is useEffect import React, { useEffect } from 'react'; useEffect(() => { const script = document.createElement('script'); script.src = "./home/public_html/example.com/wp-content/themes/sample/script.js"; script.async = true; document.body.appendChild(script); return () => { document.body.removeChild(script); } }, []); // Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “react” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”

Comment: //Another possibility is useJquery - An essential hook for your React applications github.com/latviancoder/useJquery Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module //solved with script type="module" Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' //return <div className="App" />; Some threads are recommends further extending with the 'create-react-app' module.

Comment: In React we don't generally use Jquery as these two libraries have rather orthogonal approaches to UI management. In React we don't directly manipulate or mutate the DOM, and that's just about the only thing Jquery is good for. Jquery has also about next to nothing to do with Redux, a state management library. It seems your question is really more about just using some Javascript to manipulate the DOM around a bit. This is really outside the scope of responsibility of React, but it's something you do *alongside* the React code.

Answer (score 0):

After the numerous testing among different JS modules and `Redux/React`  framework methods intended to allow `jQuery` scripts modify DOM elements, I found that actually the problem with `jQuery` custom script execution is the timing as the `jQuery` scripts are running before the actual `Virtual DOM` elements are rendered, so the solution is to have `jQuery` script running after the page/scripts are loaded with the `setTimeout` function delay.

```html
   <script>
      function OnLoadingScript(url) {
         var script = document.createElement("script");
         script.src = "https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/sample/customscript.js";
         document.head.appendChild(script);
      }
      window.onload = setTimeout(OnLoadingScript, 1000);
   </script>
```